# how to get the value in json variable in dropdownlist using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

```
<option value="PRODUCT_TYPE">1.3</option>
```

I want to get 1.3 using below code but i m not getting it....

```
var OperatingSystem = document.getElementById("<%=ddlOS.ClientID %>"); 
var size = OperatingSystem.options.length; 

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
    if (OperatingSystem.options[i].text === obj.OperatingSystem) { 
        $("#ddlos").val(i); 
        $("#ddlOS").multiselect("refresh"); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using the following:

```
var OperatingSystem = document.getElementById("<%=ddlOS.ClientID %>"); 
var size = OperatingSystem.options.length; 
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{ 
   if (OperatingSystem.options[i].text === obj.OperatingSystem) 
 { 
   operatingsystem.selectedindex=i;
   $("#ddlOS option:selected).text();
   $("#ddlOS").multiselect("refresh"); 
   break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the value returned from `html()` (or javascript `innerHTML` property) ion order to determine the visible selection content for the option.  `val()` returns the tag's `value` property which in your example would be `PRODUCT_TYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

As mike said, you can use innerHTML or Text.

You can get it with jquery like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/YNtxm/

```
function DoSomething()
{
var foo = $("select").find(":selected").text();
alert(foo);
}
```

Comment: it's not working because my dropdownlists is fill by database and i have more than 12 dropdownlists and when i enter a product_no in the textbox then all dropdownlists fill automaticallly but in my case its is not working before that is working when i doing simply operatingsystem.selectedindex=i but i want to do this like above code

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here. I would refactor to something like this:

```
var $ddl = $('<%=ddlOS.ClientID %>');
$ddl.val($ddl.find('option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == obj.OperatingSystem;
}).val());
```

Here's a demo of the javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/uQfEA/